Find the Pareto Efficient set for 3 Leontiefs
I'm struggling with the following General Equilibrium exercise:
Find the Pareto Efficient set for this Pure Exchange Economy;
The consumers are $i = 1,2,3$ with these Leontief utilities:
$u_i(x_{1i},x_{2i}) = \min(ix_{1i},x_{2i})$
Normally I would approach Leontiefs graphically but I don't know how to visualize it for 3 consumers.
I remember from previous courses the approach of maximizing the sum of all the utilities to obtain the efficient bundles. Is this valid here?
I would appreciate any help with this.

Maximizing the sum of utilities or more generally weighted sum of utilities will give you efficient allocations as solutions.
To get efficient allocations, we can solve the following problem:
$\max_{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+}\alpha_1\min(x_1,y_1)+\alpha_2\min(2x_2,y_2)+\alpha_3\min(3x_3,y_3)$
subject to $x_1+x_2+x_3=\omega_X, \ y_1+y_2+y_3=\omega_Y$
where $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3_+\setminus (0,0,0)$ and $\omega_X>0$ and $\omega_Y>0$ are given.
Solution to the above problem is necessarily Pareto efficient. As we vary $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ and consider the union of set of solutions generated in the process, we get the set of all Pareto efficient allocations.
For example: maximising the sum of utilities for the case where $\omega_X=\omega_Y=\omega>0$,
$\max_{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+}\min(x_1,y_1)+\min(2x_2,y_2)+\min(3x_3,y_3)$
subject to $x_1+x_2+x_3=\omega, \ y_1+y_2+y_3=\omega$
will give the following set of feasible allocations as solutions to the above problem:
$\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))\in\mathcal{F}|y_1\leq x_1 \wedge y_2 \leq 2x_2 \wedge y_3 \leq 3x_3\}$
Here $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of feasible allocations i.e.
$\mathcal{F}=\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+|x_1 +x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3=\omega\}$
These solutions are Pareto efficient, but not necessarily always the only efficient allocations. There can be more.
